# Can't start apache

Tags: apache

I've traditionally installed apache in my debian 7.
apt-get install apache2
and could see It works! on it's ip.
I went to /etc/apache2/sites-available and there are default and default-ssl config files. I've created my custom config:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerName ***.com
        ServerAlias leopardik.com
        AddDefaultCharset off
        AssignUserID user user
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        DocumentRoot /var/www/***.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@***.com
        ServerAlias www.***.com
        <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
                SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
                SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        </FilesMatch>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@***.com"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/***.com:."
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/***.com.access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/***.com.error.log


</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/***.com>
        php_admin_flag engine on
        Options -ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Of course I have a directory /var/www/***.com where I have test.html saying "OK"
when I try to restart apache I got:

```
Starting web server: apache2apache2: bad user name user
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Strange that I got 2 apache2 now.
This is content of error.log

```
[Wed Nov 25 20:43:05 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 25 20:43:52 2015] [error] [client ***] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://***/
[Wed Nov 25 21:36:10 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Whats wrong?
**UPD1** Where can I look more error logs? I know about `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and I posted it. 
Also owner of created *** directory is www-data, there is

```
    export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

in /etc/apache2/envvars.
In ports.conf I have

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Gonna check @Capsule answer.

Comment: Can you provide more error logs about your server start errors .. Please make sure to kill all running Apache instance and then start ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since stderr says `bad user name user`, I would try and fix that line: `AssignUserID user user`

You need a valid user and group here.